# Connecting to dcm4chee using dcm4che from a JAVA program

Tags: java, dicom, dcm4che

### Update

I dug deeper in dcm4che's source code and found that an `IncompatibleConnectionException` is thrown if either

- a connection is "not installed"
- or the types of protocols are not set or don't match.

I don't know what it means that a connection is "installed" but this flag can be set manually, so I set it for both the local and remote connections to `true` (even checked them with `getInstalled()` whether they are "installed" - and yes they are now - previously this property was `null`).

And as to the protocols, they weren't specified, so for both connections I set them to `DICOM`.

Results: I still get the same Exception.

---

I'd like to establish a DICOM association between [dcm4chee](https://www.dcm4che.org/) (2.18.3) and my JAVA application using the [dcm4che](https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4che) (5.12.0) toolkit.

The problem is that it doesn't seem to be any documentation available on how to use dcm4che in a JAVA application, so all I can do is read dcm4che's source code and try to figure out what its classes and methods are for, but I'm stuck. If someone already has a working example it would be very helpful.

So far I have:

```
import org.dcm4che3.net.ApplicationEntity;
import org.dcm4che3.net.Association;
import org.dcm4che3.net.Connection;
import org.dcm4che3.net.Device;
import org.dcm4che3.net.pdu.AAssociateRQ;
import org.dcm4che3.net.pdu.PresentationContext;

...

ApplicationEntity locAE = new ApplicationEntity();
locAE.setAETitle("THIS_JAVA_APP");

Connection localConn = new Connection();
localConn.setCommonName("loc_conn");
localConn.setHostname("localhost");
localConn.setPort(11112);
localConn.setProtocol(Connection.Protocol.DICOM);
localConn.setInstalled(true);
locAE.addConnection(localConn);

ApplicationEntity remAE = new ApplicationEntity();
remAE.setAETitle("DCM4CHEE");

Connection remoteConn = new Connection();
remoteConn.setCommonName("rem_conn");
remoteConn.setHostname("localhost");
remoteConn.setPort(11112);
remoteConn.setProtocol(Connection.Protocol.DICOM);
remoteConn.setInstalled(true);
remAE.addConnection(remoteConn);

AAssociateRQ assocReq = new AAssociateRQ();
assocReq.setCalledAET(remAE.getAETitle());
assocReq.setCallingAET(locAE.getAETitle());
assocReq.setApplicationContext("1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1");
assocReq.setImplClassUID("1.2.40.0.13.1.3");
assocReq.setImplVersionName("dcm4che-5.12.0");
assocReq.setMaxPDULength(16384);
assocReq.setMaxOpsInvoked(0);
assocReq.setMaxOpsPerformed(0);
assocReq.addPresentationContext(new PresentationContext(
    1, "1.2.840.10008.1.1", "1.2.840.10008.1.2"));

Device device = new Device("device");
device.addConnection(localConn);
device.addApplicationEntity(locAE);

Association assoc = locAE.connect(remAE, assocReq);
```

but I don't know whether I'm on the right path doing it.

The error I get:

```
org.dcm4che3.net.IncompatibleConnectionException: No compatible connection to DCM4CHEE available on THIS_JAVA_APP
at org.dcm4che3.net.ApplicationEntity.findCompatibelConnection(ApplicationEntity.java:646)
at org.dcm4che3.net.ApplicationEntity.connect(ApplicationEntity.java:651)
```

Comment: I think as an SCU you will have to use the constructor specifying the transfersyntaxes:     public PresentationContext(int pcid, String as, String... tss). The result will be filled in by the SCP (dcm4chee)

Comment: @kritzel_sw Do you know what `String as` stands for? Right now I have `PresentationContext(1, "?", "1.2.840.10008.1.2")`. What should I put in place of the `?`? Are the two other parameters right at all?

Comment: I have to guess. But I am quite confident, it should read: PresentationContext(ID, AbstractSyntax (=Verification), TransferSyntax(es)), e.g. PresentationContext(1, "1.2.840.10008.1.1", "1.2.840.10008.1.2")

Comment: @kritzel_sw It doesn't work this way either. Same exception. But thanks anyway, I'll keep on looking...

Comment: I updatede my answer also. Maybe drop the parameters from `localConn` and see what happens.

Comment: @TarmoR still the same exception.

Comment: Yeah, I'm out of ideas then. I don't have a Java dev environment set up at the moment either, to play around myself. My best suggestion is trying to take the FindSCU.java apart and see how it works. It's probably the simplest of the tools included in the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the working code: (I don't know if it's the minimal solution, feel free to experiment with it...)

```
ApplicationEntity locAE = new ApplicationEntity();
locAE.setAETitle("THIS_JAVA_APP");
locAE.setInstalled(true);

Connection localConn = new Connection();
localConn.setCommonName("loc_conn");
localConn.setHostname("localhost");
localConn.setPort(11112);
localConn.setProtocol(Connection.Protocol.DICOM);
localConn.setInstalled(true);
locAE.addConnection(localConn);

ApplicationEntity remAE = new ApplicationEntity();
remAE.setAETitle("DCM4CHEE");
remAE.setInstalled(true);

Connection remoteConn = new Connection();
remoteConn.setCommonName("rem_conn");
remoteConn.setHostname("localhost");
remoteConn.setPort(11112);
remoteConn.setProtocol(Connection.Protocol.DICOM);
remoteConn.setInstalled(true);
remAE.addConnection(remoteConn);

AAssociateRQ assocReq = new AAssociateRQ();
assocReq.setCalledAET(remAE.getAETitle());
assocReq.setCallingAET(locAE.getAETitle());
assocReq.setApplicationContext("1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1");
assocReq.setImplClassUID("1.2.40.0.13.1.3");
assocReq.setImplVersionName("dcm4che-5.12.0");
assocReq.setMaxPDULength(16384);
assocReq.setMaxOpsInvoked(0);
assocReq.setMaxOpsPerformed(0);
assocReq.addPresentationContext(new PresentationContext(
    1, "1.2.840.10008.1.1", "1.2.840.10008.1.2"));

Device device = new Device("device");
device.addConnection(localConn);
device.addApplicationEntity(locAE);

Executor exec = (Runnable command) -> {};
device.setExecutor(exec);

Association assoc = locAE.connect(localConn, remoteConn, assocReq);
```

And the relevant dcm4chee log:

```
2018-03-02 23:21:42,832 INFO  THIS_JAVA_APP->DCM4CHEE (TCPServer-1) [org.dcm4cheri.net.FsmImpl] received AAssociateRQ
    appCtxName: 1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1/DICOM Application Context Name
    implClass:  1.2.40.0.13.1.3
    implVersion:    dcm4che-5.12.0
    calledAET:  DCM4CHEE
    callingAET: THIS_JAVA_APP
    maxPDULen:  16378
    asyncOpsWindow: 
    pc-1:   as=1.2.840.10008.1.1/Verification SOP Class
        ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
2018-03-02 23:21:42,843 INFO  THIS_JAVA_APP->DCM4CHEE (TCPServer-1) [org.dcm4cheri.net.FsmImpl] sending AAssociateAC
    appCtxName: 1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1/DICOM Application Context Name
    implClass:  1.2.40.0.13.1.1.1
    implVersion:    dcm4che-1.4.34
    calledAET:  DCM4CHEE
    callingAET: THIS_JAVA_APP
    maxPDULen:  16352
    asyncOpsWindow: 
    pc-1:   0 - acceptance
        ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
```

After you have the association, [see this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36260653/5214911) for how to perform a C-FIND.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be, that You are missing a `Device` instance from Your setup? It seems, that You need a `Device`, to which You attach both `ApplicationEntity` and `Connection`.

Looking at [FindSCU.java](https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4che/blob/master/dcm4che-tool/dcm4che-tool-findscu/src/main/java/org/dcm4che3/tool/findscu/FindSCU.java) source from dcm4che source.

```
private final Device device = new Device("findscu");
private final ApplicationEntity ae = new ApplicationEntity("FINDSCU");
private final Connection conn = new Connection();

public FindSCU() throws IOException {
    device.addConnection(conn);
    device.addApplicationEntity(ae);
    ae.addConnection(conn);
}
```

I also think, that maybe the local `Connection` object can be instantiated without any parameters as the FindSCU example here demonstrates. Maybe the parameters are confusing it somehow, especially considering, that you have both local and remote connections pointing to `localhost:11112`.

But yes, one has to agree, that the documentation for dcm4che3 API is totally inadequate.

Comment: Thanks, meanwhile I also realized that a device might be necessary as I found [an older implementation](http://forums.dcm4che.org/jiveforums/message.jspa?messageID=21998) for an association, and also added some other parameters to the request based on some other forum topics I found ([this](http://forums.dcm4che.org/jiveforums/thread.jspa?threadID=1413) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dcm4che/Hmf5qj8R4A0)) so I updated my question accordingly. Unfortunately I'm still out of luck.

Comment: I assume from the new exception, that the order of operations seems to matter. Add the `Connection` to the `Device` first and then add the `ApplicationEntity`.

Comment: Thanks, you were right, now the `Device` is ok (question updated). So now that I have a `Device`, I just have to figure it out what it is for... :)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Apparently, I solved the problem. Changing the executor from

```
Executor exec = (Runnable command) -> {};
device.setExecutor(exec);
```

to

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
device.setExecutor(executorService);
device.setScheduledExecutor(scheduledExecutorService);
```

made it so my application correctly received the association response from the server. This might serve as reference for someone else.

Thank you for sharing your code. It was really helpful to me.

**Original Post**

I am unable to perform the connection with a code similar to the solution you proposed. I am trying to request an association with a dcm4chee-arc-light with dcm4che (both 5.14.1), and I have as it follows:

```
Device device = new Device(deviceName);
ApplicationEntity locAE = new ApplicationEntity(localAE);
Connection conn = new Connection();
Connection remote = new Connection();
AAssociateRQ rq = new AAssociateRQ();

device.addConnection(conn);
device.addApplicationEntity(locAE);
locAE.addConnection(conn);

ApplicationEntity remAE = new ApplicationEntity();
remAE.setAETitle(remoteAE);

remote.setCommonName("rem_conn");
remote.setHostname(remoteIP);
remote.setPort(remotePort);
remote.setProtocol(Connection.Protocol.DICOM);
remAE.addConnection(remote);

rq.setCalledAET(remAE.getAETitle());
rq.setCallingAET(locAE.getAETitle());
rq.setApplicationContext("1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1");
rq.setImplClassUID("1.2.40.0.13.1.3");
rq.setImplVersionName("dcm4che-5.14.1");
rq.setMaxPDULength(16384);
rq.setMaxOpsInvoked(0);
rq.setMaxOpsPerformed(0);
rq.addPresentationContext(new PresentationContext(
        1, "1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1", "1.2.840.10008.1.2"));

Executor exec = (Runnable command) -> {};
device.setExecutor(exec);

//Opens association and connects to remote server
Association as = locAE.connect(conn, remote, rq);
```

But when trying to connect to a remote AET, it doesn't seem to receive the AAssociation response from the remote AET. My Java application hangs in Sta5 (waiting for association response) while the server hangs in Sta6 (ready for data transfer).

Java log:

```
[main] INFO org.dcm4che3.net.Connection  - Initiate connection from 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:0 to localhost:11112
[main] INFO org.dcm4che3.net.Connection  - Established connection Socket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=11112,localport=50101]
[main] DEBUG org.dcm4che3.net.Association  - /127.0.0.1:50101>localhost/127.0.0.1:11112(1): enter state: Sta4 - Awaiting transport connection opening to complete
[main] INFO org.dcm4che3.net.Association  - DEVICEAE->DCMQRSCP(1) << A-ASSOCIATE-RQ
[main] DEBUG org.dcm4che3.net.Association  - A-ASSOCIATE-RQ[
  calledAET: DCMQRSCP
  callingAET: DEVICEAE
  applicationContext: 1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1 - DICOM Application Context Name
  implClassUID: 1.2.40.0.13.1.3
  implVersionName: dcm4che-5.14.1
  maxPDULength: 16378
  maxOpsInvoked/maxOpsPerformed: 1/1
  PresentationContext[id: 1
  as: 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1 - Study Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - FIND
  ts: 1.2.840.10008.1.2 - Implicit VR Little Endian
 ]
]
[main] DEBUG org.dcm4che3.net.Association  - DEVICEAE->DCMQRSCP(1): enter state: Sta5 - Awaiting A-ASSOCIATE-AC or A-ASSOCIATE-RJ PDU
```

Server log:

```
19:11:29,397 INFO  - Accept connection Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=50101,localport=11112]
19:11:29,397 DEBUG - /127.0.0.1:11112<-/127.0.0.1:50101(3): enter state: Sta2 - Transport connection open
19:11:29,416 INFO  - DCMQRSCP<-DEVICEAE(3) >> A-ASSOCIATE-RQ
19:11:29,416 DEBUG - A-ASSOCIATE-RQ[
 calledAET: DCMQRSCP
 callingAET: DEVICEAE
 applicationContext: 1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1 - DICOM Application Context Name
 implClassUID: 1.2.40.0.13.1.3
 implVersionName: dcm4che-5.14.1
 maxPDULength: 16378
 maxOpsInvoked/maxOpsPerformed: 1/1
 PresentationContext[id: 1
 as: 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1 - Study Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - FIND
 ts: 1.2.840.10008.1.2 - Implicit VR Little Endian
  ]
 ]
19:11:29,419 DEBUG - DCMQRSCP<-DEVICEAE(3): enter state: Sta3 - Awaiting local A-ASSOCIATE response primitive
19:11:29,419 INFO  - DCMQRSCP<-DEVICEAE(3) << A-ASSOCIATE-AC
19:11:29,419 DEBUG - A-ASSOCIATE-AC[
 calledAET: DCMQRSCP
 callingAET: DEVICEAE
 applicationContext: 1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1 - DICOM Application Context Name
 implClassUID: 1.2.40.0.13.1.3
 implVersionName: dcm4che-5.14.1
 maxPDULength: 16378
 maxOpsInvoked/maxOpsPerformed: 1/1
 PresentationContext[id: 1
 result: 0 - acceptance
 ts: 1.2.840.10008.1.2 - Implicit VR Little Endian
  ]
 ]
19:11:29,427 DEBUG - DCMQRSCP<-DEVICEAE(3): enter state: Sta6 - Association established and ready for data transfer
```

I feel like I am missing something, but I cannot find the source of the problem. Any help is appreciated, as I am still new to dcm4che and DICOM protocol.

Thank you.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @Filnor, it inicially didn't provide an answer, but it was directed towards the given answer - which doesn't work in my case. After identifying the problem, I ended up giving a different answer to the question, one that might work for people who encountered the same problem I did. I feel it is more useful to have this here than in a question referencing to this, as it is easier for people to see it in the future.